# unable to set layout page for a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a helloWorldController, for which I have created a index method

[image]

Here is the view code which is generated for me

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

and my _layout page is default ASP.NET MVC 4 layout. 
But still I am getting blank page with the string returned from the Index method.

How can I enable _Layout page for a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that screenshot is the actual code for your controller, you need to return `ActionResult` for each action method rather than string, e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The `View()` return value will work provided that there is a view called `Index.cshtml` in either your `Views\HelloWorld` or `Views\Shared` folder. The convention is that you have a specific folder with the same name as your controller for all views specifically relating to that controller - in your case `HelloWorld`